# Pre-populate select2 options on page load

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have a table with 100 records.  There is a tag column where each row has a select2 input of class ".select-tags".  The function below allows me to select tag options from a remote source in each of those inputs.

How can I prepopulate those inputs with tags that were selected in a previous session?

```
    $(".select-tags").select2({
        minimumInputLength: 3,
        multiple: true,
        separator: '||',
        ajax: {
            url: '/api/select-tags',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: "GET",
            quietMillis: 200,
            data: function (term) {
                return {
                    term: term
                };
            },
            results: function (data) {
                return {
                    results: data
                };
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hey! I have the exact same question, have you found a solution? Would really be grateful if you could direct me anywhere :). Thanks!